# D3 Make Y-Label Count by 10s instead of 5s

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

currently I'm making a simple line graph in d3, but as you will see in my image the y-label is counting by 5s which makes it look very cramped. For my particular use case having it count by 10s would work totally fine but I'm not sure how to specify this and am having a hard time searching for a helpful resource.

Here is what the graph looks like currently with the counting by 5s y-label:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/envwL.png)

And here is my relevant code for the y-label drawing (the last 4 lines being the specific drawing of the y-label):

```
const { data } = props

const width = 800
const diaHeight = 200

const diaGraph = d3
   .select('#dia-graph')
   .append('svg')
   .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr('height', diaHeight + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)
   .data(data)

const dia_yScale = d3
   .scaleLinear()
   .range([diaHeight, 0])
   .domain([50, 120])

diaGraph
   .append('g')
   .attr('class', 'y-axis')
   .call(d3.axisLeft(dia_yScale))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adjusting the suggested number of ticks in the axis through the [ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_ticks) function. It would look something like `.call(d3.axisLeft(dia_yScale).ticks(7))`. Trying different number of ticks might give you the result that you're looking for. This won't necessarily guarantee that the ticks will count by 10's. For that, you could explicitly set the values of the ticks that you want using the [tickValues](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickValues) function.